# Polymorphism in GraphQL with a one-to-many relationship

Tags: graphql

I have the following entities in my schema.

- User
- Link Post
- Normal Post

How do I model the one to many relationship between the `User` and `Post` types where `Post` can be of the two types `LinkPost` or `NormalPost`.

Answer (score 12):

I would model these schemas utilizing one of the Polymorphic types that exist within GraphQL. That approach would give you the most flexibility in querying and extension in the future.

## Schema Design

Its very convenient for a `User` to have an array of `Posts` as such:

```
type User {
  id: Int!
  email: String!
  posts: [Posts!]
  username: String!
}
```

This means that a `Post` needs to be either an `interface` or a `union` type. Either of these two types allow us to leverage the fact that `NormalPost` & `LinkedPost` are both still a type of `Post`. It will also allow us to query them in the same place just like in `user.posts` above.

#### Interfaces

An [`interface`](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) type is very similar in behavior to that of an `interface` in OOP. It defines the base set of fields than any implementing type must also have. For instance, all `Post` objects might look like this:

```
interface Post {
  id: Int!
  author: String!
  dateCreated: String!
  dateUpdated: String!
  title: String!
}
```

Any type that `implements` the `Post` interface then must also have the fields `id`, `author`, `dateCreated`, `dateUpdated` & `title` implemented in addition to any fields specific to that type. So using an `interface`, `NormalPost` & `LinkedPost` might look as follows:

```
type NormalPost implements Post {
  id: Int!
  author: String!
  body: String!
  dateCreated: String!
  dateUpdated: String!
  title: String!
}
```

```
type LinkedPost implements Post {
  id: Int!
  author: String!
  dateCreated: String!
  dateUpdated: String!
  link: String!
  title: String!
}
```

#### Unions

A [`union`](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types) type allows dissimilar types that have no requirement of implementing similar fields to be return together. A `union` type is structured differently than how it would using interfaces since a `union` type does not specify any fields. The only thing defined within a `union` schema definition are the unioned types separated by a `|`.

The only caveat to that rule is any types within a `union` that have with the same field name defined would need to have the same nullability (ie. Since `NormalPost.title` is non-nullable (`title: String!`) then `LinkedPost.title` must also be non-nullable.

```
union Post = NormalPost | LinkedPost
```

```
type NormalPost implements Post {
  id: Int!
  author: String!
  body: String!
  dateCreated: String!
  dateUpdated: String!
  title: String!
}
```

```
type LinkedPost implements Post {
  id: Int!
  author: String!
  dateCreated: String!
  dateUpdated: String!
  link: String!
  title: String!
}
```

## Querying

The above introduces the question of how to differentiate a `LinkedPost` from a `NormalPost` when querying them from `user.posts`. In both cases, you would need to use a Conditional [Fragment](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments).

A Conditional Fragment allows a specific set of fields to be queried from an `interface` or `union` type. They look the same as a regular Query Fragment as they are defined using the `... on <Type>` syntax within your Query body. There is a slight difference in how a Conditional Fragment can be structured for an `interface` vs a `union` type.

In addition to querying using the Conditional Fragment it tends to be useful to add the `__typename` [Meta Field](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#meta-fields) to your polymorphic queries so the consumer of the query can better identify the type of the resulting object in code.

#### Interfaces

Since an `interface` defines a specific set of fields that all implementing types have in common those fields can be queried like any other normal query on a type. The difference is when the `interface` types have different fields that are specific to their type, like `NormalPost.body` vs `LinkedPost.link`. A query that selects the entire `Post` interface and then the `NormalPost.body` and `LinkedPost.link` would look as follows:

```
query getUsersNormalAndLinkedPosts {
  user(id: 123) {
    id
    name
    username
    posts {
      __typename
      id
      author
      dateCreated
      dateUpdated
      title
      ... on NormalPost {
        body
      }
      ... on LinkedPost {
        link
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Unions

Since a `union` doesn't define any common fields between its types, all of the fields that to be selected must exist in each Conditional Fragment. This is the only difference between querying `interface` and a `union`. Querying a `union` type looks as follows:

```
query getUsersNormalAndLinkedPosts {
  user(id: 123) {
    id
    name
    username
    posts {
      __typename
      ... on NormalPost {  
        id
        author
        body
        dateCreated
        dateUpdated
        title
      }
      ... on LinkedPost {
        id
        author
        dateCreated
        dateUpdated
        link
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Conclusion

Both of the polymorphic types have strengths and weaknesses and its up to you to decide which is the best for your use case. I have utilized both when building out a GraphQL schema and the specific difference in when I use `interface` or `union` is if there are common fields between the implementing types.

Interfaces make a great deal of sense when the only difference between implementing types is only a small set of fields while the rest are shared between them. This leads to smaller queries and potentially less Conditional Fragments needed.

Unions really shine when you have a type that is a mask for multiple different types that are unrelated but come back together, like in a set of search results. Depending on the type of searches it return may return many different types that look nothing alike. For instance a search on a CMS that could yield both a User and a Post. In that case, it would make sense to have a the following type:

`union SearchResult = User | Post`.

This can then be returned from a query with the signature

```
search(phrase: String!): [SearchResult!]
```

In the context of this specific question I would go with the `interface` approach as it makes the most sense from a relationship and querying perspective.

Comment: this is great will try out...is there any chance you know how to query the posts using prisma client for each case??

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered to have a single `Post` entity and define the post type using a enum type?

*User*

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  posts: [Post!]!
}
```

*Post*

```
type Post {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  createdBy: User!
  type: PostType!
}
```

and the enum type for the `Post`

*PostType*

```
enum PostType {
  NORMAL
  LINK
}
```

**----- Update! -----**

If you want to have separated entities, you can just do that:

*User*

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  linkPosts: [LinkPost!]!
  normalPosts: [NormalPost]
}
```

*LinkPost* type

```
type LinkPost {
  description: String!
  url: String!
  createdBy: User!
}
```

*NormalPost* type

```
type NormalPost {
  title: String!
  description: String!
  createdBy: User!
}
```

Let me know if this works for you,

Regards

Comment: I did consider that. but the Link and normal Post type have fields that the other can't have like say Post type has a title and content fields whereas the Link type has url and description. so I was hesitant to consider this approach..

Comment: got it, I have updated my answer, let me know if this what are you looking for.